# Скрипт bash для копирования одного файла во множество директорий

Tags: bash

Не особенно разбираюсь в bash скриптах. Нужно реализовать наверное простую задачу. лежит файл по адресу А. его нужно раскопировать во ВСЕ поддиректории директории с адресом B. Буду благодорен за примеры и подсказки

Comment: Пробовали сами почитать о bash скриптах и что-то сделать?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/300744/416190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

или

`find b_directory -type d -exec cp -v path/file.txt {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то можете использовать это заклинание(первое что пришло в голову)

```
find b_directory -type d | xargs -i cp path/file.txt {}/.file.txt
```

`b_directory` --путь к корневой директории

`path/file.txt` -- путь к файлу который копировать

`{}/.file.txt` -- вместо file.txt подставить название конечного файла

В результате во всех директориях, вложенных в b_directory появится файл `file.txt`